Ubuntu unistallation from android mobile
I want to install ubuntu by userland app from playstore on my vivo y22s (android 14).
But i want to know that, after installation if I want to uninstall ubuntu then how i will uninstall ubuntu properly.
Advanced thank you.

You've not provided any link, but there is no official support for Ubuntu on phones, most of the Canonical/Ubuntu effort now is helping Android app developers use Ubuntu as their development workstation, and not official products. https://userland.tech/download/ is NOT an official Ubuntu system & as such is not on-topic here (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

There should be an option within UserLand to uninstall Ubuntu.
Uninstalling UserLand and Termux should remove all traces of Ubuntu from your android phone.
